# Cannot find element based on attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to raise a `mouseenter` event for an element, when hovering over another element. I am trying to find the element based on a data attribute:

```
 $("#modal").on("mouseenter", ".jq_pin", function(e) {
        var attr = $(this).data("abbr");
        var els = $(".jq_mapPoint");
        var el = els.find("[data-abbr='" + attr  + "']");
        el.trigger(e.type);
    });
```

My event fires, and debugging I can see a list of elements with `jq_mapPoint` class, and one has a matching data attribute, but the length of el is always 0.

Element with event:

```
<li class="jq_pin"data-abbr="N">HI</li>
```

Element Im trying to target:

```
<div style="position:absolute;left:59%;bottom:72%" class="jq_mapPoint" data-abbr="N">N</div>
```

Comment: Where is markup ? `els` will be holding many elements I guess..

Comment: I think you need to loop through els with .each, see jQuery,com for the full documentation

Comment: Yes there are many els, wont find just loop through for me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) instead of `.find()`

> Reduce the set of matched elements to those that match the selector or pass the function's test.

```
var el = els.filter("[data-abbr='" + attr  + "']");
```

instead of

```
var el = els.find("[data-abbr='" + attr  + "']");
```

Comment: @AmrElgarhy, Find looks in the descendants of element where OP need to filter the result set

Comment: Or `$(".jq_mapPoint[data-abbr='" + attr  + "'] ")`

Answer (score -1):

It probably needs the All selector `*`:

```
theels.find("*[data-abbr='" + attr  + "']");
```